# ajax json Post to Spring mvc Controller "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Hi so I am having problems with getting the JSON from my form to my work with spring mvc. My form is dynamic and the JSON comes back as a list of the criteria that the user filled out on the form. Ideally I would like to be able to get the JSON to come over as a Criterias object which contains a list of Criteria objects. (Like my model classes below) I dont know if this is possible or if there is a different way to go about it but any advice would be much appreciated.

**Currently I am receiving a 415 unsupported Media Type from the ajax post.

CONTROLLER

```
@RestController   
public class Controller {
@RequestMapping(value-"/test",method=RequestMethod.GET
public ModelAndView getTest(){

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test");

}
@RequestMapping(value-"/query",method=RequestMethod.POST
public ModelAndView submitTest(@RequestBody Criterias criterias){

//do stuff....
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("results");

}
```

MODEL

```
public class Criterias{
private List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
getter setter...
}

public class Criteria{
private String field;
private String filter;
private String operator;
private String criteria;


getters setters...
}
```

TEST.JSP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><select name = 'operator'><option>AND</option><option>OR</option></select></td><td>Field:<select name='field'><option>a</option><option>b</option> <option>c</option> <option>d</option> </select> </td> <td> <select name='filter'>  <option>Contains</option> <option>Does Not Contain</option> <option>Equals</option> <option>Does Not Equal</option> </select> </td><td>  <input name='criteria' type='text'> </td><td><button type ='button' class ='rm' title = 'Remove Row'/></td></tr>")
  });
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.rm', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});

function post() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "query",
    data: JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray())

  })

};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form>

  <table>
    <tbod>
      <tr>
        <td>Field:
          <select name='field'>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name='filter'>
            <option>Contains</option>
            <option>Does Not Contain</option>
            <option>Equals</option>
            <option>Does Not Equal</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name='criteria' type='text'>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbod>
  </table>
  <table id='myTable'>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="search" onclick="return post();">
  <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Add Criteria">

</form>
```

**UPDATE**

I attempted to do something a little simpler to narrow down the issue and from what I have looked up it seems to be a problem with the jackson mapping. The following code produces 415 error as well.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class Rest{
@RequestMapping(value="/testModel",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getTestModel(){
   return new ModelAndView("testModel");
}

 @RequestMapping(value="/sendTestModel",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String submiteTestModel(@RequestBody TestModel test){
   return test.getName();
 }
 }
```

**MODEL**

```
public class TestModel{

private String id;
private String name;

//getters setters....
}
```

**testModel.jsp**

```js
function post() {

    $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          type: "POST",
          contentType: 'application/json;,
    dataType: '
          json ',
    url: "sendTestModel",
    data: JSON.stringify({id:"1",name:"Bob"})

  })

};
```

```html
<Html>
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="return post();"/>
</Html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray())` will give you the following String

`[{"name":"field","value":"a"},{"name":"filter","value":"Contains"},{"name":"criteria","value":""}]`

Here is the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for `serializeArray()`

Clearly, this is not acceptable for a `@RestController` that expects JSON representation of Criterias object. Your JSON string should look like

`{"criteria":[{"field":"a","filter":"Contains"},{"field":"Some other field value","filter":"Some other filter value"}]}`

**I have made a simple function to do it for you :**

```
function convertCriterias(json){
    var o = new Object();
    var criterias = [];
    var c = new Object();

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        c[json[i].name] = json[i].value;
    }

    criterias[0] = c;

    o.criteria = criterias;

    return JSON.stringify(o);
}
```

Just replace `JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray())` with `convertCriterias($('form').serializeArray())`

**EDIT**

I believe you meant to use `input type="button"` instead of  `input type="submit"` for doing an AJAX post to your `@RestController`. And you meant to call `return work()` and not `return post` in the onclick event of the button.

Comment: it seems like your function only grabs one criteria group so instead of returning {"criteria":[{"field":"a","filter":"Contains"},{"field":"Some other field value","filter":"Some other filter value"}]}
It returns just the last row of whatever was selected on my form. so like this {"criteria":[{field names and values}]}

Comment: It is because you only have one field and one filter in your form. If the `serializeArray` returns many field and many filter, they will be put in returned JSON string. As for your main problem, let me know whether I explained to you clearly the root cause why you are getting `415 unsupported Media Type` from your request.

Comment: There is more than on field and filter in my form? if you run the code snippet you will see that if you click add criteria it will add new fields filters and values to the form. I tried backtracking and tried to see if I could map just one object to my JSON and I still received the 415 unsupported Media Type error

Comment: This is the JSON I tried I hardcoded it into the data in the ajax call like this..... JSON.stringify({"operator":"","field":"Text","filter":"contains","value":"hello"}) and I changed my controller to just Criteria Crit instead of Criteria[] Crit and still could not get it to map.

Comment: I know it is a mapping issue because if I change the controller to String Crit then it will bring over the JSON and store it in the string.

Comment: You are missing a closing single quote on `contentType: 'application/json;,`. After correcting this, I ran your code and it is working, I can see the `String` getting serialized to `TestModel`.

Comment: woops that just happened to be a typo on here. Still receiving 415 error. For now I just manually imported Jackson mapper and brought the json over as a string and serialized it through a mapper object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options:

- Add in your controller's RequestMapping the content-type you want to get produced. Take a look at the [Producible Media Types documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) for more information.

  @ResponseBody @RequestMapping(value="/query", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
- Explicitly specify the **Accept** request header not just the **Content-Type** header in your jQuery Ajax call:

  $.ajax({
            headers: {
                   Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },.. })

Comment: Thank you for answering but I am still receiving the same 415 error.